# Resize image in magento product view

Tags: image, magento, view, resize, product

Want to increase the size of an image on the Product view page in Magento 1.8 CE, Modern theme.
I tried to change the values from 265 to 400 in the following files:

```
/app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml

/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml

/app/design/frontend/default/default/template/featurezoom/media.phtml
```

(because this extension was installed. I have a feeling that the problem might be here, but cannot find what)

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/productdetails/media.phtml
```

even in the `/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php`

Changed the 
css file `.product-view .product-img-box .product-image {width: 400px}`

Flushed the cache, cleared the folder `/media/catalog/product/cache/`

But something still keeps creating the **265x265** folder in the cache

Here is the [page](http://advertisingmos.com/hosting/dhvision/index.php/digital-video-recorders-category/16-channel-d1-1-5u-dvr.html)

Thought it would be simple task, but already spent the entire day on it.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Did you try 'Turning On Template Path Hints' to make sure your editing the correct file.. see http://www.westwideweb.com/wp/2009/08/04/magento-how-to-turn-on-template-path-hints-and-inline-translation/

Comment: Looks like its frontend/base/default/template/productdetails/media.phtml http://advertisingmos.com/hosting/dhvision/index.php/digital-video-recorders-category/5400-series/16-channel-d1-1-5u-dvr.html?tp=1

Comment: What is the content of .../productdetails/media.phtml

Comment: /* Main Image Size */
    if (strstr($_productDetails['mainImageSize'], '_')) {
/*         $mainImageSize = explode('_', $_productDetails['mainImageSize'], 2); */
   $mainImageSize = array(400, 400); /* I commented the line above and inserted this line. The image is resized */
    } else {
        $mainImageSize = array(400, 400);
    }

Comment: Did you try changing the size in this file?

Comment: Yes I did try to change it in the ELSE statement, but it didn't work. I answered the question. Not sure if that's the proper way

Answer (score 1):

So I believe I found the solution. Thanks Nikitas for the suggestion to use the debug mode.
Not sure if this is proper way, but this works. 
The file I edited was frontend/base/default/template/productdetails/media.phtml
Initial code was

```
/* Main Image Size */
if (strstr($_productDetails['mainImageSize'], '_')) {
    $mainImageSize = explode('_', $_productDetails['mainImageSize'], 2);
} else {
    $mainImageSize = array(265, 265);
}
```

Changing the sizes in the ELSE didn't help, so I changed it in the IF statement like this

```
/* Main Image Size */
    if (strstr($_productDetails['mainImageSize'], '_')) {
/*         $mainImageSize = explode('_', $_productDetails['mainImageSize'], 2); */
        $mainImageSize = array(400, 400);
    } else {
        $mainImageSize = array(265, 265);
    }
```

If you know better solution or have any suggestions, that would be helpful. 
Thanks

Now I'll have to play with the zoom because it increased the zoom box

Comment: You should copy that file to your store theme folder /app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/productdetails/media.phtml. Also you should take a close look at how/where  $_productDetails['mainImageSize'] get it data

Comment: Thank you R.S. My zoom square increases in the size proportionally to the image. So basically, it zooms only just a little bit. Do you know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Just go to

```
/app/design/frontend/yourtheme/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml
```

Find the code

```
'image')->resize(436)
```

and just give your image dimension in here like

```
'image')->resize(300,436)
```